# Tailwind CSS: Use CSS variable as arbitrary value for font size?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind CSS, I know it is possible to use `px` and `rem` values as arbitrary values to set an element's font size:

```css
text-[6.9rem]
text-[420px]
```

But is there a way to use CSS variables as arbitrary font size values? Using a variable in place of a `px` or `rem` value to set the font size does not seem to work, as the resulting class sets the element's color i.o. its font size:

```css
text-[var(--custom-size-a)]
text-[var(--custom-size-b)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a CSS variable as an arbitrary value, wrapping your variable in var(...) isn’t needed — just providing the actual variable name is enough:

```
text-[--custom-size-a]
text-[--custom-size-b]

<!-- Will generate a font-size utility -->
<div class="text-[length:--my-var]">...</div>

<!-- Will generate a color utility -->
<div class="text-[color:--my-var]">...</div>
```

[tailwind arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#resolving-ambiguities)

Comment: Cool, I did not know that, thanks for pointing it out. But this does not solve the problem I posed, the resulting class still sets the `color` prop, not the `font-size`

Comment: try this :
<div class="text-[length:var(--my-var)]">...</div>